# Alernative for poll in primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I am using primeface 3.2. i am using ajax poll to get every reaction into th gui.But ajax poll is not get stopped.i am trying to stop in server side.
i am using stop=true to stop  the poll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Here is a link to the showcase [Poll - Start/Stop](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pollStartStop.jsf)

---

**Old**

If you want to stop the polling from the server side you could use the *RequestContext API *

Like described by *cagataycivici*

look at his (old) blog post

[How to Stop Polling From Server Side](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2011/05/23/how-to-stop-polling-from-server-side/)

Code snippet

Client

```
<p:poll listener="#{bean.listener}" update="sth"  stop="#{bean.stop}"/>
```

Server

```
private boolean stop = false;

public void listener() {
    if(condition) {
        stop = true;    
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried that i am getting the alert in java script function that means it called correctly. still poll is not get stopper.finally i redirected the page then only it gets stopped.

Comment: how about '<p:poll listener="#{bean.listener}" update="sth"  stop="#{bean.stop}"/>
'

Comment: Any luck? Does poll stop work at all in PrimeFaces? I am having the same problems... Please, comment.

Comment: @Danijel have you tried both way suggested in the link i posted?

Comment: @Daniel I tried only second one. Let me just make one thing clear: can I start the poll again once it is stoped? How? Just by setting stop to false and refreshing the `p:poll`?

Comment: @Danijel take a look at this http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pollStartStop.jsf